# Bounded stochastic process is uniformly bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes, supremum-and-infimum

I' m a worker and I'm self studying stochastic calculus. I'm struggling with the definition of bounded process. It seems to me that each author uses different definition.

Now, in the book I'm studying, there is no a specific definition of bounded process but the author says:

*If $\Pi$ is some property of a sample path, then we say the process has property $\Pi$ if every sample path $t\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ has property “$\Pi$”.*

So a bounded process $X$, that takes value in $\mathbb{R}$, on the measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ should be a proces such that for each $\omega \in\Omega $ there exists a finite constant $M_{\omega}$ such that:
$$ |X_{t}(\omega)|< M_{\omega} \; \; \; \forall t \in \mathcal{T};$$
where $\mathcal{T}$ is an index set that can be countable or not.\

My question is: can I conclude that there exists a finite constant $M$ such that:
$$| X_{t}(\omega)|< M \; \; \; \forall t \in \mathcal{T} \; \forall \omega \in \Omega$$
defining:
$$ M=\sup_{\omega \in \Omega} M_{\omega}$$.

In the title I called this property uniformly boundedness.

Comment: Brownian motion on $[0,1]$ is an example.  Every sample path is continuous and hence bounded, but for any constant $M$ there is a positive probability that the Brownian motion travels further than $M$ from the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, without further assumptions, it is not possible to conclude uniform boundedness. For example, let $X_t(\omega)=Y(\omega)$ where $Y$ is a non bounded random variable (that is, $Y\notin \mathbb L^\infty$ or $\mathbb P(\lVert Y\rVert\gt n)>0$ for all $n$). For example, if $\Omega$ is $(0,1)$ endowed with the Lebesgue measure, take $Y\colon\omega\mapsto 1/\omega$.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand. If $X_t(\omega)=Y(\omega)$ for every $t$ and $Y(\omega)$ is unbounded, how can we find for each $\omega$ a constant $M_\omega$ such that $$X_t(\omega)=Y(\omega)< M_\omega$$?

Comment: Take $M_\omega=Y(\omega)+1$.

Comment: Maybe I am confused, but if $Y(\omega)$ is unbounded your $M_{\omega}$ could be not finite for some $\omega$? Am I wrong?

Comment: I meant that the values of $Y$ are finite, but $Y$ is not essentially bounded in the sense written in the edit.

Comment: Maybe I' ve understand. Can you give me an example of such function? If I have understood well the function $f: ] 0 ;+\infty[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\omega \mapsto ln(\omega)$ is this kind of function.

Comment: Yes: I added an example.